# "Stream connection lost: ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None)"

Tags: python, rabbitmq, backend, publish-subscribe, messagebroker

I am trying to connect rabbitmq to python and run a basic hello world..!! program but the connection show this error:

> "Stream connection lost: ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing
> connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054,
> None)"

here is my code for connection and consuming the message:

```
connection = pika.BlockingConnection(
        pika.ConnectionParameters(host='localhost'))
    channel = connection.channel()

    channel.queue_declare(queue='hello')

    def callback(ch, method, properties, body):
        print(" [x] Received %r" % body)

    channel.basic_consume(queue='hello', on_message_callback=callback, auto_ack=True)

    print('Waiting for messages. To exit press CTRL+C')
    channel.start_consuming()
```

please help out..!!

Comment: Do you maybe have the same session opened in the browser? Could it be possible that the pika connection is lost at some point if the user is already logged in other place?

Comment: yes you guessed right  user is already logged in other place